# Woocommerce / Wordpress - Add button to Order / Product Page on Admin Panel

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add a button and or text to both the order page and product page of the admin panel of woocommerce. They are actually both types of `/wp-admin/post.php` but evidentally different post types. Is this possible? I have look through the available hooks on the woocommerce list and the only ones I have tried actually put information on the listings page of each.

Just looking for the filter/hook!

Many thanks in advance, sorry for no code samples - not applicable as just looking for an identifier!!

Comment: Found the answer myself, please see answers!

Answer (score 3):

In order to add a custom button to the Woocommerce Order Page (On Admin Page) you need to use `add_meta_boxes` wordpress action we can then use a filter for `shop_order` so it only display on the woocommerce orders. So code would look something like this...

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'MY_order_meta_boxes' );
function MY_order_meta_boxes()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'woocommerce-order-YOUR-UNIQUE-REF',
        __( 'The title of my box' ),
        'order_meta_box_YOURCONTENT',
        'shop_order',
        'side',
        'default'
    );
}
function order_meta_box_YOURCONTENT()
{
  echo '<button>New button</button>';
}
```

You then would want your button to do something, so it is work adding some JS into that last function also. Then you are probably likely to want to use Wordpress AJAX which you can read about and see a demo [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: Which source file would this go in? Presumably it has to be somewhere in a child-theme?

Comment: Nope in a plug-in.